# How to make a table / diagram like this?

Tags: diagrams, arrows

[image]

Need to create three blocks side by side. Each block having texts and itemized lists inside them. Double arrow in between them. Also, can this be made better in someway? like changing the arrow type something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
      box/.style={draw, text width=4cm, thick, inner sep=4pt, text depth=53mm}
     ,arrow/.style={-{Stealth []}, line width=3pt}
  ]
  \node[box] (s1)
    {%
      \textbf{Step-1} Problems generalization \& strategies aggregation
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Problems generalization based on the SC difficulties of \emph{PRAN
          Foods Ltd.}
        \item Strategies aggregation according to their categories
      \end{itemize}%
    };
  \node[box, right=of s1] (s2)
    {%
      \textbf{Step-2} Strategies prioritization
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Pair-wise comparison data collection
        \item Strategy's weight calculation based on expert's opinions
        \item Prioritization of strategies based on their global weights
      \end{itemize}%
    };
  \node[box, right=of s2] (s3)
    {%
      \textbf{Step-3} Intensity measurement and mitigations
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Bullwhip intensity measurement techniques development
        \item Bullwhip mitigation strategies proposition
      \end{itemize}%
    };
  \draw[arrow] (s1) -- (s2);
  \draw[arrow] (s2) -- (s3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it looks fine. but when i pasted the code into my document, it looked something like this: https://imgur.com/a/IUIrzdh  The text overflows the bottom border of the box.

Comment: @GMIqbalMahmud change the value of `text depth` to the values needed for your document settings. I don't want to invest the time writing a solution that auto-sizes correctly, sorry.

Comment: No worries. I have tried a different approach but the texts in the boxes are not aligning to the top automatically. How can I align them at the top? https://imgur.com/a/aGSaPe5

Comment: For example like I did in my answer by setting the `text depth` to some magic value that fits. Or you typeset each box "dry" once, detect which one is the biggest, and draw the frame of the biggest one around each box.

Comment: And if you don't need all the boxes to have the same size, but still want them top aligned, you could do `right=of s1.north east, anchor=north west` for the placement of `s2`, and `right=of s2.north east, anchor=north west` for `s3`. Then you'd also need to adapt the arrows, e.g., with `\draw[arrow] (s1) -- (s2.west|-s1);` and `\draw[arrow] (s2.east|-s1) -- (s3.west|-s1);` so they are horizontal.

Comment: Thank you so much!